# Saving the text from an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to save the text from an EditText, I got it working, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly. When I reopen it in my app it's fine, but when I pull it from the device and I open it in windows notepad I lose the line-breaks.

```
...     
        try {
            BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
            buf.append(cv.getText().toString());
            buf.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What's the correct way to save large EditText's full of text?

Comment: Windows uses `\r\n` as a line-break while Unix uses `\n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing the right thing - the problem is that Notepad doesn't understand [Unix line termination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) conventions.

Open the file in Wordpad, and you'll see it should be displayed correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks! You're right. Is there anything I can do to correct it though?

Answer (score 2):

Try `buf.append(cv.getText().toString().replace("\n", "\r\n");` to make the linebreaks readable in Windows programs.